# How to create SSRS report using procedure that returns data based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that returns number of columns based on parameter @SearchType. So first it checks what is the parameter value, then SELECT statement returns data.

My problem is how can I use this procedure in SSRS? It doesn't bring me any columns so I can add it to a table or matrix.

In SSMS the procedure works fine. 
There gotta be a work around for that.

Thanks

[image]

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RPT_spLoadUserOpenTasks
      (
        @UserGUID varchar(8000) = NULL,
        @NoteStoreType INT = NULL,
        @DateFrom datetime = NULL,
        @DateTo datetime =NULL,
        @LineGUID varchar(8000) = NULL
      ) 

AS
 IF @SearchType = 0
 BEGIN 
       SELECT DISTINCT 
            TOP 100 PERCENT 
                Column1,
                Column2,
                Column3
                --other columns
         FROM 
                  dbo.tblNoteEntities  (nolock) 
           --some other JOINs here 
         WHERE tq.LineGuid IN (SELECT * FROM @LineTable)
                AND               
                  (@UserGUID IS NULL OR tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID = @UserGUID) 
             ORDER BY  Column1
      RETURN
END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if @SearchType = 1  --eq and eq access 
BEGIN 
SELECT DISTINCT 
            TOP 100 PERCENT 
                Column4,
                Column5,
                Column6
         FROM 
                  dbo.tblNoteEntities  (nolock) 
           --some other JOINs here 
         WHERE tq.LineGuid IN (SELECT * FROM @LineTable)
                AND               
                  (@UserGUID IS NULL OR tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID = @UserGUID) 
             ORDER BY  Column1
      RETURN
END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if @SearchType = 3 --And so on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the columns of your query outputs manually in the dataset.

Since column names and number is not static try to do so by having each query to return the same number of columns having empty data for columns not required.

For each value of your parameter, create the table containing the required columns and set table visibility depending the selected value of the parameter (for example if parameter has 3 values you have to create 3 tables but only one will be visible each time).

Comment: Thanks. The number of columns will be different depending of parameter value. Are there any similar examples somewhere?
Thanks

Comment: I will update my answer to match your case. I think Microsoft reports for CRM are similar to what you are asking

Comment: Great. I will try to do that. Also the stored procedure can return all the columns, its just gonna be bunch of NULLs. But then I can hide columns in SSRS depending on the parameter by writing expressions. Do you think that would be better approach? Especially in terms of performance. 
Thanks

Comment: If you want to print the report then I think its better to go with the multiple table solution otherwise this may cause empty pages when printing because of the report width. From the performance perspective I think there will be little difference in rendering time between hidden columns and hidden tables.